# How to retrieve a list of the original variable names from a GLM call in R?

Tags: r, glm, feature-selection, model-fitting

When using the `glm` function in R one can use functions like `addNA` or `log` inside the `formula` argument. Let's say we have a dataframe `Data` with 4 columns: `Class`, `var1` which are factors and `var2`, `var3` which are numeric variables and we fit:

```
Model <- glm(data  = Data, 
         formula   = Class ~ addNA(var1) + var2+ log(var3),  
         family    = binomial)
```

In the glm output variable 1 will now be called `addNA(var1)` (e.g. in `Model$xlevels`), while variable 3 will be called `log(var3)`.

Is it possible to retrieve a list from the glm output that indicates that var1, var2 and var3 were extracted from the dataframe, without addNA(var1) or log(var3) appearing in the variable names?

More general, is it possible to infer which columns were extracted from the input dataframe by glm prior to any transformations / cross terms etc being generated inside the glm function, *after* the call to glm has been made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
all.vars(formula(Model)[-2])
## [1] "var1" "var2" "var3"
```

The `[-2]` indexing removes the response variable from the formula.  However, you may be disappointed that the internally stored model frame does not have the original variables, but the transformed variables ...

```
names(model.frame(Model))
## [1] "Class"       "addNA(var1)" "var2"        "log(var3)"
```

If you want the raw names, then `all.vars(getCall(Model)$formula)` should work.

Comment: I'd like to add (though not for this question) that `[[2]]` refers to the right-hand side if the left-hand side is absent. E.g., `(~x1+x2)[[2]]` is `x1 + x2`. See `?"~"`.

Answer (score 1):

The returned list includes `call`,  `formula`, and `terms` items.  You should be able to extract whichever specific parts you want from those elements.  If you really want just the source names (which is pretty obvious from the returned `terms`, then run a `gsub` to remove everything prior to "(" in the names, and to remove the trailing ")" .